# How to avoid the focus on Delphi application?

Tags: delphi, focus

I need develop an application (Delphi) that never receive the focus, I use the DLL to display the video on second monitor (I found in Torrys Delphi - Dr.SAGURA Media Player v.1.0) that receive the focus every time play the video, how avoid this ?
I try :

```
procedure TForm.WMActivate(var Msg: TWMActivate);  
begin  
  WA_ACTIVE :
  begin  
    Msg.Result := 0;// cancel focus  
  end;  
end;
```

Unsuccessful !

Thanks
Jean Alysson

Comment: As written, that looks like it shouldn't compile.

Comment: looks like he meant to have a case statement there. :-)

Answer (score 3):

- In your project DPR set Application.MainFormOnTaskBar := False.
- Override the form's OnShow and OnActivate events and add this to both of them: ShowWindow(Application.Handle, SW_HIDE);
- Override your form's CreateParams procedure and add WS_EX_NOACTIVATE to Params.ExStyle.

The first two items hide the application from the taskbar and the Alt+Tab list and the last keeps it from gaining focus when it's shown and when clicking on it.

Comment: Ok Craig, thanks by explanation to solve my problem, your solution works very well, and thanks to show me the way to write my doubts  :-)

Answer (score 0):

What's the intention behind not be focusable? You want to avoid the user from closing/minimize/maximize the window?
Maybe your need can be acomplished understanding the real problem.

Maybe having a sevice instead of a regular application can make the trick.

Comment: I use the application to display the video on second monitor, instaled in the same computer.